# Rendering only a single mesh in an environment and having everything else (behind it & overlapping it) masked out/transparent

Tags: rendering, transparency, render-layers, masking

I have a completed scene in which I wish to render all the animated characters separately from the stationary environment, with everything but the characters being transparent (including everything that might cover/overlap parts of those characters); like masking out all of the environment parts around them and then rendering only the character and their animation as separate PNG frames.

I haven't worked with layers or the compositor very much and I can't quite figure out how I would go about it. If there is an easier way of only rendering the single mesh with the environment masked out do let me know!

[image: Example of what I wish to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the objects that you want to be transparent in the same collection and activate the *Holdout* option for this collection:

[image]

Don't forget to activate the *Render > Film > Transparent* option:

[image]